# Physical vs internal value in AUTOSAR

Tags: data-conversion, autosar

I have been struggling with the conversion of values in AUTOSAR from internal to physical values and vice versa. I understand this:
The physical value is the value we send to the application, and the internal value is the one we get after quantizing the physical value which is then sent on the bus. Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The software is exclusively working with the internal values. In rare cases, internal values are identical to their physical counter-part.

The definition of a conversion formula of values in the internal domain to and from the physical domain has mainly two use cases:

1. Provide human-readable values in measurement and calibration tools and diagnostic testers.
2. The definition of a `CompuMethod` on both ends of a communication can be taken to compute a conversion formula of the transmitted data (internal values) from the sender to the receiver in case sender and receiver have use different resolution of the data. This aspect is explained in more detail in the AUTOSAR document „SWS RTE“.